# What I must do to activate my site

Tags: maintenance

When I go to my site it shows " Sorry, your Website is in work". My question is how I can do that this is not there and all can see my site.

Comment: Please state your question in english.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is supposed to be written in English.

Comment: When I go to my site ther stand " Sorry, your Website is in work". My question is how I can do that this are not there and all can see my site.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the *`maintenance.flag`* file from the Magento root.